# How to jail a specific user to a specific directory?

Tags: ftp, user-management

I am new to Ubuntu and also Linux, but I don't find it that hard, I am just stuck at this. So, I am setting up FTP (didn't choose which to use yet) on my VDS, but I have a problem. I don't know if it is even possible, but I want to do this:

1. Jail gameserver users (gameserver1, gameserver2...etc) to /home/username
2. Create and jail ONE web user to /var/www

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, the chroot is done on the user home directory. It then depends on which ftpd server you use. For example, for proftpd: [UserDirRoot directive](http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_UserDirRoot.html) and [DefaultRoot directive](http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html)